# Remote Visual Studio Performance Profiler Get Lines of Code C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling

I am running a standalone C# application on a Windows virtual machine and I attach a VSPerf Performance Profiler to the process. When I copy the resulting .vsp file over to my PC, I can view the file and see samples for modules in the file, but I want to see the line of code in the module that consumes the most CPU usage. Is this possible? I have looked at the MS documentation on VSPerf Performance profiling and nothing has worked. I have tried

```
vsperfreport /summary:all /packsymbols filename.vsp
```

but this just unpacks the .vsp into csv files, but still no lines. I have also tried

```
/samplelineon
```

with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it for me. The important thing is to load the symbols properly:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/creating-ngen-pdbs-for-profiling-reports